Collision doesn't work under very specific circumstances
This is my player's update function:
void update() {
    IsOnWall = false;
    IsOnFloor = false;
    int collide[4] = { collidelist(Rect{pos.x, pos.y + vel.y, hitbox.width, vel.y + 1}, Stillbodies),
                        collidelist(Rect{pos.x, pos.y + hitbox.height, hitbox.width, vel.y - 1}, Stillbodies),
                        collidelist(Rect{pos.x + vel.x, pos.y + 1, vel.x - 1, hitbox.height - 1}, Stillbodies),
                        collidelist(Rect{pos.x + hitbox.width, pos.y + 1, vel.x + 1, hitbox.height - 1}, Stillbodies) };
    if (collide[0] >= 0 && vel.y <= 0) {
        vel.y = 0;
        pos.y = Stillbodies[collide[0]].y + Stillbodies[collide[0]].height;
        IsOnFloor = true;
    }
    if (collide[1] >= 0 && vel.y > 0) {
        vel.y = 0;
        pos.y = Stillbodies[collide[1]].y - Stillbodies[collide[1]].height;
    }
    if (collide[2] >= 0 && vel.x <= 0) {
        vel.x = 0;
        pos.x = Stillbodies[collide[2]].x + Stillbodies[collide[2]].width;
        IsOnWall = true;
    }
    if (collide[3] >= 0 && vel.x > 0) {
        vel.x = 0;
        pos.x = Stillbodies[collide[3]].x - hitbox.width;
        IsOnWall = true;
    }
    IsOnWallOnly = (IsOnWall && !IsOnFloor);
    IsOnFloorOnly = (IsOnFloor && !IsOnWall);
    pos.x += vel.x;
    pos.y += vel.y;
    hitbox.x = pos.x;
    hitbox.y = pos.y;
}

The if collide[0] part works most of the time, but if my player's y velocity is exactly the height of the object it's colliding with, it clips the player in for 1 frame. At least, that's what I've found so far. All the other ifs work perfect, even under the same circumstances.
Here is a minimal reproducible example:
Code
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
class Rect {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    Rect(int X, int Y, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        width = WIDTH;
        height = HEIGHT;
    }
};
class Spot {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    Spot(int x1, int y1) {
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
    }
};
bool colliderect(Rect rect1, Rect rect2) {
    return (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
        rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
        rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
        rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y);
}
int collidelist(Rect rect, std::deque<Rect> rects) {
    for (float rec = 0; rec < rects.size(); rec++) {
        if (colliderect(rect, rects[rec])) {
            return rec;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
std::deque<Rect> Stillbodies = { {0, 0, 50, 50} };
int main() {
    Spot pos = Spot(0, 50);
    Rect hitbox = Rect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50);
    Spot vel = Spot(0, 0);
    while (true) {
        char move;
        std::cin >> move;
        if (move == 'u') {
            vel.y = -50;
        }
        else if (move == 'd') {
            vel.y = 50;
        }
        else {
            vel.y = 0;
        }
        int collide[4] = { collidelist(Rect{pos.x, pos.y + vel.y, hitbox.width, vel.y + 1}, Stillbodies),
                                collidelist(Rect{pos.x, pos.y + hitbox.height, hitbox.width, vel.y - 1}, Stillbodies),
                                collidelist(Rect{pos.x + vel.x, pos.y + 1, vel.x - 1, hitbox.height - 1}, Stillbodies),
                                collidelist(Rect{pos.x + hitbox.width, pos.y + 1, vel.x + 1, hitbox.height - 1}, Stillbodies) };
        //broken collision (other ones that look same work)
        if (collide[0] >= 0 && vel.y <= 0) {
            vel.y = 0;
            pos.y = Stillbodies[collide[0]].y + Stillbodies[collide[0]].height;
        }
        //this one works
        if (collide[1] >= 0 && vel.y > 0) {
            vel.y = 0;
            pos.y = Stillbodies[collide[1]].y - hitbox.height;
        }
        pos.x += vel.x;
        pos.y += vel.y;
        hitbox.x = pos.x;
        hitbox.y = pos.y;
        std::cout << pos.x << " " << pos.y << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Input/Output (with added comments)
n //n is just an example for nothing
0 50 //nothing happens. wow
u // u for up
0 0 //you go up but the block is there
n //nothing
0 50 //it pushes you out
u //up
0 0 // same outcome
u //up
0 -50 // now above block, yo can waltz through in the actual game too
d //down
0 -50 // collision working
d //down
0 -50 //double checking


Do you consider touching rectangles a collision? Or only if they overlap? (Not targeting a problem, just for my easier understanding.)

I propose to improve your (already good-looking) MRE by hardcoding the inputs instead of telling us what they are (e.g. by calling helper functions like moveup(), moveleft()). Consider also adding some output of interesting variables. Your venting ("grr") I totally understand and do not consider them a problem in your question, but they might be perceived differently by other users.

Consider to align the < and > in your code. Just a matter of taste, which I however would do, in order to facilitate the double and triple checking of that surely important part of code. If you don't mind, but do not actually know in detail what I mean consider allowing me to edit your code for that purpose - functionally neutral of course.

I kind of miss, inside the second if within update() something like IsAtCeil, just to complete the pattern. Please explain why it is not there. I do see by the way that floor and wall do not have an influence, it just triggers my desire for complete patterns....

@Yunnosch I deleted the last two in the input/output section. I did this late last night and was quite annoyed. Also the reason I did not add an IsOnRoof i because i did not see a purpose but it may be useful to others using this little thing once i post it. Btw this is my second win32 project. I am trying to make a mix between a game engine and a library, like if godot2d was code only. Thats why I wont use any easy solutions that work for my specific cause.

Better focus on your question now. Improve it according to [ask]. Make a MRE without unneeded future extension points. That does not exclude structure like helper functions. I recommend not to show functions you do not call. And maybe you do not focus on the one thing I said is unimportant in my eyes.

Please post the solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

@Yunnosch I do not believe anything is unneeded in the mre. Can you point out what is.

I do not mean to remove anything from your MRE (apart from maybe all the input, after hardcoding it). But you I consider the uncalled function update() unneeded and I proposed a few things to do or add to your MRE in my first comment.

I found out the issue;
When the velocity is negative, I wasn't flipping it yet was accounting for it as if it was negative;

So would you like to show the relevant part of the fixed code?
